# Parsing notification information from distribution lists

Tags: c#, beginner, linq

I'm writing am application that I've previously posted questions on here, but I'm looking for similar advice if possible. I am looking for how best to write my code, as I have a working example, but to me it feels long winded.

The application first grabs 3 tables via DataContext:-

```
        var contacts = db.GetTable<Contact>();
        var distributionLists = db.GetTable<DistributionList>();
        var JunctionTable = db.GetTable<ContactsDistribution>();
```

I then get the selected items from my listbox, which are distribution lists. A contact can be in more than one distribution list, so I first get the raw data from my database:

```
var listBoxItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().Select(t => t.ToString());

var initialList = (from j in JunctionTable
                      where listBoxItems.Contains(j.DistributionName)
                      join c in contacts on j.ContactID equals c.ContactID
                      select new { c.ContactID,c.Surname,j.DistributionName, j.EmailFlag, j.SMSFlag}).ToList();
```

I then need to search the `initialList` collection for users who require email notifications.  I also need to remove duplicate entries, as a Contact can appear multiple times. So the list is made Distinct:-

```
var email = (from l in initialList
                       where l.EmailFlag.Equals(true)
                       select new { l.ContactID }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I then do the same search for Contacts that require SMS Notification from the selected lists:

```
var sms = (from l in initialList
                       where l.SMSFlag.Equals(true)
                       select new { l.ContactID }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now that I have lists for both SMS & Email Notifications I need get the required email address or mobile number by doing this:

```
var smsMobileNumbers = (from s in sms
                        join c in contacts on s.ContactID equals c.ContactID
                        select new { c.MobileNumber }).ToList();

var emailAddresses = (from m in email
                     join c in contacts on m.ContactID equals c.ContactID
                     elect new { c.EmailAddress }).ToList();
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing this code or is there a better, more efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

The only change I would make would be to remove the two statements where you create the lists *sms* and *email*.  They are redundant: by adding the EmailAddress and MobileNumber to the query where you are creating the *initialList*, you can do a select on the *initialList*.

```
var initialList = (from j in JunctionTable
                where listBoxItems.Contains(j.DistributionName)
                join c in contacts on j.ContactID equals c.ContactID
                select new { c.ContactID, c.Surname, c.EmailAddress, c.MobileNumber, 
                                j.DistributionName, j.EmailFlag, j.SMSFlag }).ToList();
```

I changed these more because I like this syntax better than the SQL like Linq.

```
var emailAddresses = initialList
    .Where(l => l.EmailFlag)
    .Select(l => l.EmailAddress).Distinct().ToList();

var smsMobileNumbers = initialList
    .Where(l => l.SMSFlag)
    .Select(l => l.MobileNumber).Distinct().ToList();
```